# How to Subtract Days From Date in TypeScript

Tags: datetime, typescript

I would like to subtract days from the current date in TypeScript. 
For example, if the current date is October 1st, 2017, I would like to subtract 1 day to get September 30th, 2017, or if I want to subtract 3 days I would get September 28th etc.

This is what I have so far, the result is I received December 31st, 1969. Which I assume means that tempDate.getDate() is returning zero, as in the Epoch of January 1, 1970.

This is my code, the goal is to return the previous working day.

```
    protected generateLastWorkingDay(): Date {

        var tempDate = new Date(Date.now());
        var day = tempDate.getDay();


        //** if Monday, return Friday
        if (day == 1) {
            tempDate = new Date(tempDate.getDate() - 3);
        } else if (1 < day && day <= 6) {
            tempDate = new Date(tempDate.getDate() - 1);
        }

        return tempDate;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getDate` returns the date of the month (1-31), so creating a new `Date` from it treats that number as "milliseconds since epoch".

What you probably want is to use `setDate` to change the date as it automatically handled going backwards through months/years.

```
protected generateLastWorkingDay(): Date {
  const lastWorkingDay = new Date();

  while(!this.isWorkingDay(lastWorkingDay)) {
    lastWorkingDay.setDate(lastWorkingDay.getDate()-1);
  }

  return lastWorkingDay;
}

private isWorkingDay(date: Date) {
  const day = date.getDay();

  const isWeekday = (day > 0 && day < 6);

  return isWeekday; // && !isPublicHoliday?
}
```

Comment: `new Date(Date.now())` is redundant. You can simply do `new Date()`.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I did

```
let yesterday=new Date(new Date().getTime() - (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
let last3days=new Date(new Date().getTime() - (3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

We need to minus `(no_of_days) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` from current date.

Answer (score 4):

You can just

```
const current = new Date()
```

and then

```
const numberOfDaysToSubstract= 3;

const prior = new Date().setDate(current.getDate) - numberOfDaysToSubstract);
```

you can see an example of this here

https://codepen.io/Jeysoon/pen/poNZRwd?editors=1112